# How to disable JSplitPane arrow button

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jsplitpane

How do I disable(grey-out) the arrow button on the JSplitPane. I do know how to get the button from BasicSplitPaneDivider like this:

```
final int UP_ARROW = 0;
final BasicSplitPaneUI ui = (BasicSplitPaneUI) splitPane.getUI();
final BasicSplitPaneDivider divider = ui.getDivider();
final JButton upArrowButton = (JButton) divider.getComponent(UP_ARROW);
```

, but when I try `upArrowButton.setEnabled(false)`, it doesn't grey-out the up arrow, but does disable it. I want the user to have a visual feedback that the up arrow button is disabled. I did try `upArrowButton.getAction().setEnabled(false)`, but it doesn't work(NullPointerException).

Please help

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried `setOneTouchExpandable(false)`?

Comment: I have setOneTouchExpandable(true) because I want the user to use the up/down arrow but at the same time, I also want to set a limit the direction of expand/collapse arrows.

Comment: ops, and what if you set upArrowButton  a null icon (or a very small one)?

Answer (score 1):

```
final int UP_ARROW = 0;
final BasicSplitPaneUI ui = (BasicSplitPaneUI) splitPane.getUI();
final BasicSplitPaneDivider divider = ui.getDivider();
final JButton upArrowButton = (JButton) divider.getComponent(UP_ARROW);

upArrowButton.setVisible(false);
```

This work for me